# sencha build process add other tasks like in gulp

Tags: extjs, cmd, build, gulp

we have a offline application with the sencha extjs framework. To fill the cache.appcache file we currently using a c# exe to get all files in all subfolders and write the app cache file.
There is no way in build the appCache file once because the files are changing on different projects..

I'm coming from a gulp environment and I'm missing the possibility to adjust the build process to my wishing.
Is there a good way to achieve gulp like behavior with sencha CMD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way I wanted but could achieve all I needed with ant tasks in build.xml.